# Smart hard disk error with raw partitions

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have two raw partitions is that the  reason of smart hard disk error 301
if **i format them the hard will be ok to use again or it is about to die?**??

Answer (score 1):

SMART data is not dependant on formatting. If your SMART tool says discard, then discard [or try another tool for a second opinion]